# Angular 7 what is equivalent of JQuery on , event listener in Angular to find Modal Show

Tags: angular, modal-dialog, addeventlistener, show

I am looking for an Event Listenter to catch modal show event, something like this on JQuery but in Angular 7

```
    $('#modaldemo4').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
               $('#modalCloser').trigger('click')
                                                       })
```

I have try this but not work

```
  this.modaldemo4.nativeElement.addEventListener('modal-shown', function () {
              this.modalCloser.nativeElement.click();
              this.modalCloser2.nativeElement.click();
              this.routToFacilityValidationPage();
            });
```

what is bootstrap modal opening or showing event in angular 7.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to actually emit the `modal-shown` event. You're listening for it, but there is nothing emitting it. I'm not sure what the class looks like for the modal, but it's already listening for that `shown.bs.modal`, you may be able to listen for that.

Otherwise, if you have a button that is showing it, you could put a flag on the button that handles the visibility of the modal.

```
<button (click)="openModal()"></button>
```

And in your .ts file something like:

```
openModal() {
this.modalVisible = true;
}
```